# Is there any way to trigger Builder method in ShelRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router, gorouter

```
  return ShellRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return LoadingOverlay(
      child: RoutingBottomNavigationBar(
        paths: paths,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  },
  routes: _appRoutes,
);
```

is there any way to trigger **builder** method in **ShellRoute** or rebuild the widget which is returned in the build method from another widget

Comment: you have few options: `ListenableBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder` / `AnimatedBuilder` etc